# Get data from vuex store and select first option in variable

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

What is the correct approach to fetch data using (using vuex actions), get the data and set the first item as selected option?

What I've got right now is a `AddUser` form with a selectbox for a role. In the created function I'm calling a fetchRoles function using vuex to fetch the available roles from the backend. I created a computed property `roles` to get the roles back from the store. Finally I want a local `selectedRole` variable with the first role as default.

```
<script>
    export default {
        created() {
            this.$store.dispatch('roles/fetchRoles');
        },
        computed: {
            roles() {
                return this.$store.getters['roles/roles'];
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                selectedRole: this.roles[0],
            };
        },
    };
</script>
```

Because data is running before computed `this.roles[0]` is undefined. I can change the code to `this.roles.length > 0 ? this.roles[0] : null` but the variable isn't updated when the roles are finally available. A possible solution could be to use a watch property but I feel like there must be a better approach for this concept.

**Extra code**

**fetchRoles action**

```
export async function fetchRoles(context) {
    try {
        if (context.state.roles.length === 0) {
            const response = await axios.get('roles');
            const roles = response.data.roles;
            return await context.commit('setRoles', roles);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }
}
```

**setRoles mutation**

```
export function setRoles(state, roles) {
    state.roles = roles;
}
```

**roles getter**

```
export function roles(state) {
    return state.roles;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can await the `fetchRoles` actions and assign your variable after;

```js
async created() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('roles/fetchRoles');
    this.selectedRole = this.roles[0];
}
```

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    posts: null
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchPosts() {
const posts = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then((response) => response.json());
  this.commit('setPosts', posts)
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setPosts(state, posts) {
      state.posts = posts;
    }
  }
})



var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data: {
    firstPost: null
  },
  computed: {
    posts() {
      return this.$store.state.posts;
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('fetchPosts');
    this.firstPost = this.posts[0];
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.2/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-if="firstPost">
    firstPost : {{ firstPost.title }}
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working! Thanks!